# How to merge Pandas DataFrames with row replication?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I have two DataFrame that look like this:

```
    bin     last_4  brand       name    chargeback
0   112233  1234    visa        Joe     0
1   445566  5678    visa        Susy    0
2   778899  9012    mastercard  James   0

    bin     last_4  chargeback
0   112233  1234    1
1   445566  5678    1
```

I want to get the following result:

```
    bin     last_4  brand       name    chargeback
0   112233  1234    visa        Joe     0
1   445566  5678    visa        Susy    0
2   778899  9012    mastercard  James   0
3   112233  1234    visa        Joe     1
4   445566  5678    visa        Susy    1
```

I have already tried several attempts of `pd.merge()` method. However when I called `pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='outer', on=['bin', 'last_4'])` I got only 3 rows with duplicated 'chargeback' column like this:

```
    bin     last_4  brand       name    chargeback_x    chargeback_y
0   112233  1234    visa        Joe     0               1.0
1   445566  5678    visa        Susy    0               1.0
2   778899  9012    mastercard  James   0               NaN
```

And when I call `pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='outer', on=['bin', 'last_4', 'chargeback'])` I got `NaN` values in 'brand' and 'name' columns:

```
    bin     last_4  brand       name    chargeback
0   112233  1234    visa        Joe     0
1   445566  5678    visa        Susy    0
2   778899  9012    mastercard  James   0
3   112233  1234    NaN         NaN     1
4   445566  5678    NaN         NaN     1
```

So do you know how can I get these replicated rows with full information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat` with `pd.merge`:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2.merge(df1.drop('chargeback', axis=1),how='left',on=['bin', 'last_4'])])
Out[1]: 
      bin  last_4       brand   name  chargeback
0  112233    1234        visa    Joe           0
1  445566    5678        visa   Susy           0
2  778899    9012  mastercard  James           0
0  112233    1234        visa    Joe           1
1  445566    5678        visa   Susy           1
```

Since, the second dataframe has some missing information, `merge` the first dataframe with the second, but don't merge in the 'chargeback' column. Then, `concat` this new merged dataframe with the first dataframe.